# Variable height columns, background color

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm attempting to create a two column row using Bootstrap.  The first column should have a grey background coloring.  I can't seem to get the col-xs-* to extend to 100% of the height of the row.

A fiddle can be seen here:
http://jsfiddle.net/Kikketer/6AM4J/

There are two ways I'm trying to do this:

1. Have the first column have the grey background, and extend it to 100% height (doesn't work).
2. Make the .row class have the grey color and make the second column overwrite it with a white background.

-HTML:

```html
<div class="ex_wrapper">
    <div class="ex_1_row row">
        <div class="ex_1_key col-xs-6">Some Content</div>
        <div class="ex_1_val col-xs-6">Lots of content that causes a wrap</div>
    </div>
        <div class="ex_1_row row">
        <div class="ex_1_key col-xs-6">Another Header</div>
        <div class="ex_1_val col-xs-6"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

-CSS:

```css
/** Example 1 would just have the key highlight in grey **/
.ex_1_key {
    background-color: lightgrey;
    height: 100%;    /** notice the 100% doesn't seem to work **/
}

/** Example 2 colors the whole row, and covers things in white **/
.ex_2_row {
    background-color: lightgrey;
}

.ex_2_val {
    background-color: white;
}
```

Both of these methods fail.  I'm currently using option #2, but when the value has no content, the field shows up as mostly grey (since it's height is less than the key).

Here's an image of what I'm trying to do:

[image: Both rows have grey keys, white values. Regardless if the value has data.]

Has anyone had this problem?  What did you do to resolve the issue?  Changing the data isn't really an option.

Comment: Can you not apply something like `min-height:1em;` to your value field? Otherwise, outside of using `flexbox`, you might have to resort to tiling a background image on your row.

Comment: The min-height worked, sort of... I guess the other test case that I don't have here (that I'm not worried about) is if the key is spanning more than one line.  Basically the min height would have to change then based on the actual height of the key.

Comment: Thanks for the image. Helped us know what exactly you needed. See me solution below.

Answer (score 0):

A solution that considers the third test case where the Key column might be multi-line too:

Add the following attributes to `.ex_2_val`

```
padding-bottom:5000px;
margin-bottom:-5000px;
```

And add `overflow:hidden;` to `.ex_2_row`.

Try sample Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/jg9bd/

Also you can get other methods here: http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/